# Google Search Appliance: How to filter by partialfields when values have brackets e.g. ()

Tags: urlencode, google-search-appliance

We have a problem when trying to search using the partialfields parameter, on a meta tag that has a value that contains brackets.

The URL below is what we are generating when we try to search for results with meta tags of:

- `department_code`=`abc` OR `xyz`
- `region_code`=`Asia (excl Japan)`

The URL we generate to call GSA is similar to this:

```
?oe=UTF-8&output=xml_no_dtd&client=my_client&getfields=*&filter=0&site=my_site&start=0&num=100&q=foo&sort=date:D:S:d1
 &partialfields=%28department_codes%3Aabc%7Cdepartment_codes%3Axyz%29.%28region_code%3AAsia+%2528excl Japan%2529%29
```

The documentation says to [double URL-encode](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/50/xml_reference#request_meta_filter) the names and values. I thought I had done this. Starting with `%28region_code%3AAsia+%2528excl Japan%2529%29` in http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/.

After clicking decode once I get: `(region_code:Asia %28excl Japan%29)`

After clicking decode once more I get: `(region_code:Asia (excl Japan))`

To me this sounds like I have encoded it twice.

What am I doing wrong? How should the meta tag value be encoded in the URL?

Comment: Did you get it working? I am having similar issue with & characters.

Answer (score 0):

According to the GSA documentation, any non-alphanumeric characters other than decimal point, ampersand and underscore are treated as spaces in requiredfields and partialfields:

http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1077773

So, I don't think you need to encode your brackets. Or rather, encode them as spaces (%25%20).

That said, you would probably be better served by more easily machine-readable metadata in the future.